# ComboBox SelectedValuePath Validation not working

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, combobox

I am trying to implement data **validation** in XAML / WPF for the very first time. I have read several tutorials and there seems to be a variety of ways to do it. I have settled on one approach and it is not working.

First, this is ideally how I would like the error displayed (**above** the `ComboBox` and to the **right** of the `Label`). If that is possible ...

[image: Location for validation error]

I created a `ValidationRule`:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace OCLMEditor.ValidationRules
{
    class StudyPointValidationRule : ValidationRule
    {
        public bool BibleReading { get; set; }

        public StudyPointValidationRule()
        {
            BibleReading = false;
        }

        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            if(value == null)
                return new ValidationResult(false, "The study point has not been set.");

            int iStudy = (int)value;
            if(BibleReading)
            {
                if(iStudy > 17)
                    return new ValidationResult(false, "Maximum study point for bible readings is 17.");
            }
            else
            {
                if(iStudy == 7 || iStudy > 51)
                    return new ValidationResult(false, "Study points 7, 52 and 53 are not permitted for student items.");
            }

            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I added this to my `Window` class in XAML:

```
xmlns:ValidationRules="clr-namespace:OCLMEditor.ValidationRules":
```

In the `Window.Resources`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="StudyPointValidationTemplate">
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="20">!</TextBlock>
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then, for my first ComboBox where I want this validation applied I changed it from:

```
<ComboBox DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=oclmEditor}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ReadingStudyPointsList}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StudyPointComboBoxStyle}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StudyPointComboItem}"
          Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource StudyPointValidationTemplate}"
          Tag="{Binding Meeting.BibleReadingMainName, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Meeting.BibleReadingMainStudyPoint, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          SelectedValuePath="Number"/>
```

To:

```
<ComboBox DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=oclmEditor}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ReadingStudyPointsList}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StudyPointComboBoxStyle}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StudyPointComboItem}"
          Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource StudyPointValidationTemplate}"
          Tag="{Binding Meeting.BibleReadingMainName, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Meeting.BibleReadingMainStudyPoint, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          >
    <ComboBox.SelectedValuePath>
        <Binding Path="Number">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ValidationRules:StudyPointValidationRule BibleReading="True"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding> 
    </ComboBox.SelectedValuePath>
</ComboBox>
```

I get this error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Number' property not found on 'object' ''OCLMEditorViewModel' (HashCode=17586541)'. BindingExpression:Path=Number; DataItem='OCLMEditorViewModel' (HashCode=17586541); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectedValuePath' (type 'String')

I don't understand why because I was able to use "Number" previously.

### Update

I have extended my Model Data classes to throw an exception if the value is too high. For example:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public int BibleReadingMainStudyPoint
{
    get { return _TFGW.BibleReadingItem.Main.StudyPoint; }
    set
    {
        if (value > 17)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Maximum Bible reading study point is 17.");

        _TFGW.BibleReadingItem.Main.StudyPoint = value;
        MarkDirty();
        OnPropertyChanged("BibleReadingMainStudyPoint");
    }
}
```

I definately get the exception thrown:

> Parameter name: Maximum Bible reading study point is 17.
>      at OCLMEditor.Data.MeetingInfo.Meeting.set_BibleReadingMainStudyPoint(Int32 value) in D:\My Programs\OCLMEditor\OCLMEditor\Data\MeetingInfo\Meeting.cs:line 234
>      at OCLMEditor.OCLMEditorViewModel.set_SelectedStudentItem(Student value) in D:\My Programs\OCLMEditor\OCLMEditor\ViewModels\OCLMEditorViewModel.cs:line 184'

And I changed the XAMl since the ValidationRule does not apply in this instance:

```
<Binding.ValidationRules>
    <ExceptionValidationRule/>
</Binding.ValidationRules>
```

So I was expecting it to now show the error visually. No nothing on screen.

The resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ValueConverters:StudyPointWorkingOn x:Key="StudyPointWorkingOn" />

    <Style x:Key="StudyPointComboBoxStyle" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding Number}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StudyPointWorkingOn}">
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Tag"/>
                        <Binding Path="DataContext" ElementName="oclmEditor" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                        <Binding Path="Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="StudyPointComboItem">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/>
            <TextBlock Text=" - "/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="StudyPointValidationTemplate">
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="20">!</TextBlock>
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
        </DockPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
```

### Update 2

I can just make out that there is a validation symbol on teh screen. But it has not reduced the width of the combo so it can be seen.

Comment: Can you confirm, your `OCLMEditorViewModel` has a Number-Property?

Comment: @lokusking No it does not. The Number property is part of the ComboBoxItem object. You can see what the SelectedValue/Path is in the code that works.

Comment: You can't set SelectedValuePath that way because it is a String. It stores  the path that is used to get the SelectedValue from the SelectedItem

Comment: @CiccioRocca If I move `SelectedValuePath` back to where it was then, how do I tell it to do `Validation`?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle You could do it directly on the combobox selected item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SelectedValuePath` is a string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath(v=vs.110).aspx). It tells the `ComboBox` which value of the selected data item to assign to the `SelectedValue` property. There's nothing to validate about that; that's not the property that tells you what the user selected. It shouldn't change when the selection changes, because `Number` is always the property you want to use for `SelectedValue` (unless you change the type of the items in the `ComboBox` -- but that's not what you're doing).

The property you want to bind with validation is `SelectedValue`, which you've got as an attribute in your question.

```
<ComboBox
    ...other properties...
    SelectedValuePath="Number"
    >
    <ComboBox.SelectedValue>
        <Binding 
            Path="Meeting.BibleReadingMainStudyPoint"
            Mode="TwoWay"
            UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
            >
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ValidationRules:StudyPointValidationRule BibleReading="True"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding> 
    </ComboBox.SelectedValue>
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style 
            TargetType="ComboBox" 
            BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}"
            >
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                    <Setter 
                        Property="ToolTip"
                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thanks.For some reason though this ValidationRule only seems to be triggering when I shut the application down (where I get it to do a manual source update). It should be validating when the SelectedValue changes.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Is that the case when you apply the validation to `SelectedValuePath`, or to `SelectedValue`?

Comment: When `Meeting.BibleReadingMainStudyPoint` is changed in my code the ComboValue gets revised. Since the value is 25, I am expected it to get validated and show some kind of error rather than just showing an null selection from the combo list.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Does it make a difference if you make `StudyPointValidationRule` a `public` class?

Comment: No it doesn't. I also added in `NotifyOnValidationError="True"`. What I have worked out so far is that this validation only happens when I actually change the combo selection with the mouse. But it does not get fired when the `Meeting.BibleReadingMainStudyPoint` gets changed programatically.

Comment: Tied in with this, is that, even if I massage the validation rule so that i can get it to trigger when picking an item in the combo, I still don't visually see anything come up on the screen. But that is a secondary issue. Worth another question. But i shoudl eb able to trigger the validation rule when the property bound too is changed.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle It makes a certain kind of sense to me for a Binding to invoke the ValidationRules when the Source value changes on a Binding, but that appears not to be the way it works. At any rate it won't do that for me either. On the other hand, you could argue that in MVVM terms, the viewmodel should be responsible for ensuring that its own state is valid, and it should never rely on a view to take responsibility for any of its logic -- though of course that means you've got the same validation logic in two places.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle As for the error not showing up visually, something in `StudyPointComboBoxStyle` may be the culprit. I've got a plan ComboBox I'm testing with, and it's showing a red border for validation failure. But it looks like you've got something quite a bit more elaborate, so there's likely something awry in that. I mean, XAML being XAML, there's always at least three obscure things wrong the first time you try anything new.

Comment: I see. I just assumed that the right thing to do is use a validation rule. I can certainly test the value myself, perhaps when they select the student from the grid and just before I update things I validate the value. And if it is not OK tell the user or something that they have to fix it. But it still feels like a "validation error" to me.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle The idea is you have both -- that you have a validation rule to tell the user what he did wrong, *and* the viewmodel is supposed to know enough not to do anything wrong itself. I see exactly what you mean, but you have to think of a viewmodel as something that can function perfectly well all by itself, without any view at all.

Comment: The logic in my case is that I have study points. They get pre-assigned. But you only use study points 1 to 17 for certain items. So if you select a student, and their next study point was 23, and you are going to use them for the item that only goes up to 17, the user needs to know this. They will still have 23 to work on another time, but in this instance another number up to 17 must be picked.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle That's something that the viewmodel absolutely has to enforce on itself. You can share that logic by writing a static method that takes a study point number and an item ID and returns true if the combination is a valid one -- then the viewmodel and the validation rule could both call that static method.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle You can also use IDataErrorInfo for validation, which keeps it all within the viewmodel. I'll update my answer with an example

Comment: OK, thanks. I also updated my question with more details.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I can't figure out how to make IDataErrorInfo do what you want. If you want to display the error in the UI, you have to do that explicitly. I'll add a a simple illustrative example of that to my answer.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle ExceptionValidationRule is working for me with the simple tooltip binding I added to my answer. If I were you, I'd temporarily comment out all the error templating stuff you've got in your combobox style, see if it works with the default stuff and a simple error content binding to ToolTip as in my example, and then once you've got that working I'd ask a new question about your error template. Right here we've traveled a long way from your initial question about binding SelectedValuePath.

Comment: Thanks. This is where I am at: 1. I have adjusted the error template and can now show a nice rectangle around the control if there is a validation error. 2. I can only trigger the validation error when selecting a combo item. I will close off the question. Do a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this if you want to achieve the validation:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Number" DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=oclmEditor}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ReadingStudyPointsList}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StudyPointComboBoxStyle}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StudyPointComboItem}"
          Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource StudyPointValidationTemplate}"
          Tag="{Binding Meeting.BibleReadingMainName, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Meeting.BibleReadingMainStudyPoint, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          >
    <ComboBox.SelectedValue>
                <Binding Path="Meeting.BibleReadingMainName"  UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                   <ValidationRules:StudyPointValidationRule BibleReading="True"/>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </ComboBox.SelectedValue>
</ComboBox>
```

Use the `SelectedValuePath` just for tell which property use to get the `SelectedValue` from the `SelectedItem`.